# How to implement "share with network" functionality using LAMP

Tags: php, mysql

I have these tables, members, my_connections, my_thoughts.
How do I add a "Share with your network" functionality where a member can share their *thoughts* with people they are connected to in my_connections.

Comment: No info about data stored in each table. No code to show what have you tried. No errors to analyze.

Comment: Writing code and defining any additional needed table schema would be a good start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy. In the `my_thoughts` table add another column - `shared`, which will be a boolean (I use tinyint, 0 or 1). Then, to select all thoughts that have been shared by my friends:

```
select * from
    my_connections c
    join my_thoughts t on (c.connection_id=t.my_id)
where
    c.my_id=<insert my ID here>
    and t.shared=1
```

That's assuming that table `my_connections` has the columns `my_id` and `conection_id`, and that table `my_thoughts` has a column `my_id`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate the explanation as-well. Thank you.